# Values of a particular column of CSV file is not fetched properly in Json payload (Karate Framework)

Tags: karate

I am working on specified scenario too. 
My .csv file is as follows:

[image]

And test steps are:

```
Scenario Outline: Create new content value for movie: '<Movie>'
    When json payload = {'attributes':[{'entity_attribute_id': 41,'value': '<Genre>'},{'entity_attribute_id': 42, 'value': '<Language>'},{'entity_attribute_id': 39,'value': '<Movie>'},{'entity_attribute_id': 101,'value': '2020-12-03'}],'entity_type_id': '10'} 
    Given url baseUrl + postContentValues   
    And request payload
    When method post
    Then status 200
    And print response
    And def contentId = response.id

    Examples:
    |read('RoughTable.csv')  |
```

On test execution, **"Movie" are not fetched** while "Genre" & "Language" are obtained as expected from .csv file

[image]

**Please guide me for solving this issue.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be an issue with CSV loading. Can you add an extra dummy column before `Movie`.

Either way, please submit a way to replicate, this will help us fix it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hello @Peter, problem seems to be on loading first column of CSV file. As suggested by you, I tried running the script by inserting a new column "SrNo" to the left of "Movie" column. Now, Movie column values are properly fetched.

Comment: @PriyankaB I leave it to you whether you want to help us fix this or not

Comment: I think this issue should be fixed @Peter because adding a new column is just a hack to make things working. Also, It can be a bit tricky for large CSV file.

Comment: @PriyankaB for the last time, please submit a way for us to replicate. if you can't, don't ask us to fix it

Comment: I just used the CSV shared by my team. No replication steps present for this in particular @Peter

They shared .xlx file , I resaved the same file by .csv file

Comment: @PriyankaB we are trying to find what is so "special" about this file. there are plenty of ways to replicate, you can just remove all rows except 1 or 2 and change the names if needed and then replicate. but I guess this is too troublesome for you. all the best

Comment: Sorry @Peter, I will try replicating this issue using other file as suggested by you. And update you if it is observed again. I know I am troubling you but you are the only person I am looking upto.

Comment: I tried replicating this issue. Now, "Movie" column values are obtained properly. 
But Facing different issue now. Steps: Download CSV file around 10 rows > Deleted all rows after row no. 4 > Ran the karate script > Required rows fetched properly, **But Script also ran for deleted deleted rows with blank movie name**

Comment: @PriyankaB read this again: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue