# In Karate Framework, Is there a way to extract individual string (separated by comma) of a particular column in CSV file?

Tags: karate

Following is the CSV file which I am using:

[image]

I want to extract individual string from "Cast" column e.g. "Zareen Khan".

My Requirement:

1. Extract comma separated string from "Cast" column.
2. Get its **"id"** from mysql DB. (select id from table_name where name = "Zareen Khan")
3. Pass "id" in next api's Url param.

**Note: Above steps will be iterative for each row in CSV file** i.e. After "Zareen Khan", follow above steps for "Karan Kundra", "Tobby Hinston", "Sonia Armstrong" etc.

Comment: Thank you @PeterThomas for answering the questions raised by me. I read the document shared by you and have accepted (or upvoted) the answers.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any string is a Java string behind the scenes.

```
* def raw = 'foo,bar,baz'
* def array = raw.split(',')
* match array == ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: I tried using following steps:
       **And def cast = '<Cast>'
 And def array = cast.split(',')
 And print array**
I am getting the data as follows : 
["Zareen Khan","Karan Kundra", "Tobby Hinston", "Sonia Armstrong"]

**Since, the array is dynamic for each movie. Please guide me to handle individual string fetching and passing the string in next api url like "Zareen+Khan"**

Comment: @PriyankaB either read this or ask a new question: https://github.com/intuit/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

Comment: Trying to understand the link which you shared

Comment: @PriyankaB take your time. I'm still waiting for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61919918/143475

Comment: I am able to get 1st array element in "Zareen+Khan" format. But unable to fetch remaining elements e.g. ["Zareen Khan",**"Karan Kundra", "Tobby Hinston", "Sonia Armstrong"**]. Please guide me @Peter.